# HDF5 Functions and Smart Destructors - std::unique_ptr()

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, hdf5, hdf

Many HDF5 functions are initialized as follows

```
hid_t handler = DoSomething(someHandler);
```

And one has to manually free the memory reserved by such an operation using something like:

```
freeme(handler);
```

So it's the same nightmare/problems that come along by using `malloc` and/or the `new` operator.

I want to create something like `unique_ptr` to handle this at destruction. **The problem, however, that every different function has a different freeing function**.

For example:

```
hid_t attribType = H5Aget_type(attribHandler);
```

must be freed with

```
H5Tclose(attribType);
```

But this function

```
attribHandler = H5Aopen(obj_id,"name",H5P_DEFAULT);
```

Must be freed with

```
H5Aclose(attribHandler);
```

So I need to write a class that can take `hid_t` as template parameter (that's easy), and also can take the freeing function as some kind of parameter, and call it on destruction.

What's the best way to achieve this?

---

**Update**

It was suggested to me to use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter, but this doesn't work because `std::unique_ptr` expects a pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<hid_t,std::function<herr_t(hid_t)>> attribType(H5Aget_type(attribHandler), [](hid_t f) { return H5Tclose(f); });
```

This creates a compile error due to the second parameter, the lambda function. The error says (g++ 4.9):

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘hid_t {aka int}’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<int(int)> >::pointer {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
         std::unique_ptr<hid_t,std::function<herr_t(hid_t)>> attribType(H5Aget_type(attribHandler), [](hid_t f) { return H5Tclose(f); });
                                                                                                 ^
```

The error happens because `std::unique_ptr` expects hold a pointer to `hid_t`, not an `hid_t` object.

Is there a way around this? I think I can write my own class that does this now (I can use std::function to answer my first question), but would be great if I could use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` takes a deleter as an extra template parameter. `std::shared_ptr` takes a deleter as an optional extra constructor parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh! Let me try that!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please check the update.

Comment: *"`std::unique_ptr` expects a pointer"* False. `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` works with `Deleter::pointer`, which may or may not be `T*`. You'd need to invest a bit more work into creating a suitable custom deleter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own handler class... it turned out it's not that difficult:

```
template <typename T, typename Deleter>
class SmartHandle
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Deleter deleter_function;
private:
    T _value;
    Deleter _deleter;
public:
    SmartHandle(T value, Deleter deleter);
    ~SmartHandle();

    T get();
};

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
SmartHandle<T,Deleter>::SmartHandle(T value, Deleter deleter)
{
    this->_value   = value;
    this->_deleter = deleter;
}

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
T SmartHandle<T,Deleter>::get()
{
    return _value;
}

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
SmartHandle<T,Deleter>::~SmartHandle()
{
    _deleter(_value);
}
```

To use it:

```
SmartHandle<hid_t,std::function<herr_t(hid_t)>> attribType(H5Aget_type(attribHandler.get()), [](hid_t f) { return H5Tclose(f); });
```

Here `attribHandler` also uses a `SmartHandle`, which is why there's a `.get()` there.

Comment: You forget to delete copy constructor and assignment (Rule of 3).

Comment: @Jarod42 You're absolutely right. This is just quick and dirty :)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
struct MyDeleter {
  typedef hid_t pointer;
  typedef void (*FreeFunc)(hid_t);
  FreeFunc free_func_;

  MyDeleter(FreeFunc free_func) : free_func_(free_func) {}
  void operator()(hid_t f) const { free_func_(f); }
};

std::unique_ptr<hid_t, MyDeleter> p(
    H5Aget_type(attribHandler),
    MyDeleter(H5Tclose));
```

Comment: Thank you... I have to say though that writing my own class is much simpler than this. I did that already actually because I though you'll never respond. +1 for trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
template <typename Factory, Factory factory,
          typename Deleter, Deleter deleter>
class SmartHandleH5;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts, Ret (*factory)(Ts...), 
          void (*deleter)(Ret)>
class SmartHandleH5<Ret (*)(Ts...), factory, void (*)(Ret), deleter>
{
public:
    template <typename ... Us>
    SmartHandle(Us&&... args) : handler(factory(std::forward<Us>(args)...)) {}

    // Not copyable
    SmartHandle(const SmartHandle&) = delete;
    SmartHandle& operator =(const SmartHandle&) = delete;

    // Not movable
    SmartHandle(SmartHandle&&) = delete;
    SmartHandle& operator =(SmartHandle&&) = delete;

    // To avoid strange case with our template constructor
    SmartHandle(SmartHandle&) = delete;
    SmartHandle(const SmartHandle&&) = delete;

    ~SmartHandle() { deleter(handler); }

    const T& get() const { return handler; }
    T& get() { return handler; }

private:
    Ret handler;
};
```

And then use the mapping factory/destructor once:

```
using SmartHandlerGetType = SmartHandlerH5<decltype(&H5Aget_type), H5Aget_type,
                                           delctype(H5Tclose), H5Tclose>;

using SmartHandlerOpen = SmartHandlerH5<decltype(&H5Aopen), H5Aopen, 
                                        delctype(H5Aclose), H5Aclose>;
```

and use it:

```
SmartHandlerGetType attribType(attribHandler);
SmartHandlerOpen attribHandler(obj_id, "name", H5P_DEFAULT);
```

In addition, you might want to add an extra layer to hide completely `hid_t`

```
template <typename SmartHandle>
class HidHandle : private SmartHandle
{
public:
    using SmartHandle::SmartHandle;

    void foo() { someFunctionUsingHid(get()); }
};
```

and

```
using HidHandleGetType = HidHandle<SmartHandlerGetType>;
using HidHandleOpen = HidHandle<SmartHandlerOpen>;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for working this out (+1). While your solution is perfect, I don't like having to use multiple lines to call a single handle.